# Migrating AWS Neptune Snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I have taken a snapshot of a Neptune cluster which is on Neptune Engine V1.0.x and when I try to restore it I am getting an option to create a cluster with engine versions 1.0.x or 1.1.x.
The option to restore it on a cluster with engine version 1.2.x is not present.

If engine version 1.0.x and 1.1.x reach their end of life, then how would a snapshot created from engine version 1.0.x get restored?

Is it possible to migrate AWS Neptune snapshot from one engine version to another?

Answer (score 2):

I reached out AWS support and got a response for this query.

As per them, there are significant changes in the architecture starting from engine version 1.1.1.0 and that's why db engines on 1.0.x.x must be upgraded to 1.1.1.0 before upgrading to 1.2.x.x.

Also, there is no way to restore snapshots which are on 1.0.x.x to 1.2.x.x once they reach their end of life. Only way to restore those snapshots will be to restore the snapshot before end of life, upgrade the restored cluster, and then take a new snapshot of the upgraded cluster.